# TRANSACT SQL: "max recursion exhausted" error but good results for recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

The following recursive query should select the four Fridays after the current day:

```
 DECLARE @friday date
 DECLARE @today date

 Set @friday = '2016-09-02'
 Set @today = convert (date, getdate())

 While (datediff(dd, @Friday, @today) % 7) != 0
 BEGIN
 Set @today = DATEADD (dd, 1, @today) 
 END;

 With FourFridays (Friday) as (
 Select @today
 union all
 select DATEADD(DD, 7, Friday)
 FROM FourFridays
 )

 Select * from FourFridays 
 OPTION(MAXRECURSION 3)
```

The results I get look good, but I get a "maximum recursion 3 has been exhausted before statement completion" error in SQL Server Management Studio.  Any ideas?

Comment: MAXRECURSION doesn't make the recursive CTE at a certain point per se, it just tells SQL to produce an error if you go any deeper than three recursions. To stop at three recursions without an error, you need to have some sort of WHERE statement with whatever logic is required. By the way, rather than using a recursive CTE, you could simply do `SELECT DATEADD(DD, N*7, @today) Friday FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3)) T(N)`

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of MAXRECURSION.  I thought that it cut the query off after the specified number of recursions.  Manuela's example below incorporates the WHERE statement you suggested.  I like your alternate solution too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preview where your recursion would lead without maxrecursion errors:

```
DECLARE @friday date
 DECLARE @today date

 Set @friday = '2016-09-02'
 Set @today = convert (date, getdate())

 While (datediff(dd, @Friday, @today) % 7) != 0
 BEGIN
 Set @today = DATEADD (dd, 1, @today) 
 END;

 With FourFridays (Friday, Recursion) as (
 Select @today, 1
 union all
 select DATEADD(DD, 7, Friday), Recursion + 1
 FROM FourFridays
 where  Recursion < 10
 )

 Select * from FourFridays 
 --OPTION(MAXRECURSION 3)
```

Comment: I'm glad. Please marks the answer as correct when it works